# Tokbox api issue - No clients are actively connected to the OpenTok session

Tags: laravel, video-streaming, chat, broadcast, tokbox

I am using tokbox php api library.Session is successfully generating but when I call

```
startBroadcast(String  $sessionId, Array  $options = array());
```

and I am getting this error

> "No clients are actively connected to the OpenTok session".

I am using the Laravel platform.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the session and have at least one client connect to the session before you can publish the broadcast. I'm guessing you're starting the session and trying to broadcast immediately after in the same request? have two requests, one to initialize the session and one to call immediately after your client has connected to start the broadcast.